# How to check against a database for a specific entry using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am creating a login screen where I get the user Id and password from the form .How do I use the entity framework to check if a duplicate id already exists in the database ?

I am using entity framework  4 and asp.net 4.0

I am really new to the entity framework so a simple response would be very helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using Membership authentication or your own? What is your data model?

Comment: I am using my own model,the code is as follows

var objuser = new PrepLicensingSolution2010.DAL.User();
 if (txtPassWord.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                string strHashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassWord.Text, "sha1");
            }
            objuser.username = txtEmailAddress.Text;
            objuser.Password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassWord.Text, "sha1"); ;
            objuser.userRole = "member";

Comment: Edit your question and do not post code to comments.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate id? So do you want to validate that login is correct or do you want to check that login already exists during creating a new user?

If you want to validate login use:

```
bool exists = context.Users.Any(u => u.Login == userName && u.Password == pwdHash);
```

If you need to retrieve user to make validation on the client (which is absolutely not needed) you can just call:

```
var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == userName);
```

This call will return null if user with passed user name doesn't exist.

If you want to check that login is free during new user registration you can generally use `Any` as well but you must do the check and insert in the same serialized transaction - that can have performance impact in high traffic database. The other approach is placing unique constraint on the user name in the database and simply try to save a new user. If the user name exist you will catch the exception.