# How to retrieve a specific record using the entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have a table users which stores three values i.e username ,the password and the member type .I want to ensure that the username stored in the table is unique and hence there is a primary key on it.However I want to do the validation at the client side itself instead of sending a insert request to the database and then catching the error .

So how can I retrieve the single record from the database which would contain both username and password so that I can use it for the comparison purposes in the code and then throw a validation error if needed.

My manager wants me to use stored procedures so inputs along those lines would be great

Comment: I _hope_ that that's a password **hash**, and that it includes salt or (better) uses `bcrypt`.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in ASP.NET membership functionality? It even uses stored procedures for everything it does!

Comment: @ SLaks , The password is hashed using SHA1 authentication ,I intend to retrieve the password and match it against the hashed user entered password provided I have validated that the user exists in the database,what I am struggling to do is get that specific user id

@Joel C the person I am working for does not want me to use the in built asp.net membership functionality hence the need for a self defined one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check against a database for a specific entry using entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940027/how-to-check-against-a-database-for-a-specific-entry-using-entity-framework)

Comment: Well, better for you I guess, assuming you're billing hourly ;)

Comment: You asked the same question before. If you don't like the answer modify your first question instead of starting the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsUserExists(string userName, string hashedPassword)
{
  bool result = false;

  using (MyEntities entityContext = new MyEntities())
  {
    result = (entityContext.User.Count(u => u.username == userName && 
                                            u.password == hashedPassword) == 1);
  }

  return result;
}
```