# User Validation in MVC4 With Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to validate a user and on `Http Post` the code is below. and i researched some site and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940027/how-to-check-against-a-database-for-a-specific-entry-using-entity-framework). So i referred it.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(Admin admin)
{                                         //admin is the model
    if(ModelState.IsValid && IsValidAdmin(admin.Username, admin.Password))
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
    return View();
}
```

and IsValidAdmin is a method as follow:

```
public bool IsValidAdmin(Admin admin)
{
    bool isValidAdmin = false;
    //here i want to check the username and password if exists in the database;
    //using (var db = new DbContext(AdminContext) )
    {
        var myUser = db.admin.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == admin.Username
    }
    return isValidAdmin;
}
```

but i am not sure how to initialize the `db`. My Model is Admin and Context is AdminContext

I am using Entity framework and **totally new** to VS .net and entity framework but familiar with MVC.

**Please help**

Answer (score 1):

Your AdminContext class inherits from DBContext.

```
public bool IsValidAdmin(Admin admin)
{
    bool isValidAdmin = false;
    //here i want to check the username and password if exists in the database;
    using (var db = new AdminContext() )
    {
        var myUser = db.admin.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == admin.Username)
        if(myUser != null)
        {
            // do your check here.
        }
    }
    return isValidAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsValidAdmin(Admin admin)
{
    bool isValidAdmin = false;
    //here i want to check the username and password if exists in the database;
    using (var db = new AdminContext() )
    {
        return db.admin.Where(u => u.Username == admin.Username).Count() == 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check combination login && password. If it exists, allow login.

```
logins lg = null;
using (AdminContext db = new AdminContext())
{
    lg = db.logins.FirstOrDefault(x =>
         x.Username == Username.Trim()
         && x.login_pass == md5.Trim()
    );
}
return lg == null;
```